# no puedo asociar dominio de NIC argentina a Firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, txt

compre un par de dominios en NIC argentina de índole .ar y .com.ar y tengo 2 paginas web en firebase hosting de google. en la misma para asociar la pagina a tu dominio utiliza un sistema tipo CNAME, en cambio en la pagina de NIC solo me permite delegar dominio a un server especifico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hay alguna forma de compatibilizar ambas plataformas para poder asociar el dominio?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error? ¿Qué ocurre cuando le das a `Verificar`?

Comment: no entiendo de donde sacar el TXT, como dijo otro usuario nic solo te permite delegar, te pide un host y ya esta no hay mas informacion qu esa. Y si se realiza por firebase desde donde/?

Answer (score 2):

Hola dejo mi solución a mi propio problema. Jeje.
Para todas las personas que deseen utilizar su dominio .ar en firebase lo que tienen que hacer es buscar un servidor de dns gratuito. Una vez conseguido deberan delegar su dominio al servidor y el mismo le proporciona el cpanel para poder asociar el dominio a firebase. Ya que este asocia registro txt y a al servidor dns.
Tambien pueden usar el servidor dns de google pero hasta donde averigue es pago.

Comment: porque wiki? te confundiste?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Dato para la posteridad: Pude hacerlo rápido y gratis con `cloudns.net`

Answer (score 0):

El proceso para agregar el dominio a Firebase Hosting son dos pasos:

- Firebase verifica que eres dueño del dominio; para esto necesitas agregar el registro TXT que te indica el *wizard*; en [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#domain-key) puedes ver ejemplos para varios proveedores, pero consulta la documentación del tuyo para ver su sintaxis exacta.
- Una vez que el TXT se ha propagado, el siguiente paso es "*apuntar*" tu dominio a los servidores de Firebase; para ello necesitas agregar dos registros más de tipo A, que son direcciones IP, y que el mismo *wizard* te da en el siguiente paso, pero también las puedes encontrar en la misma liga de la documentación.

Ambos pasos son necesarios para poder agregar el dominio a Firebase Hosting, y si tienes algún problema, puedes comunicarte con el Soporte de Firebase, adjuntando lo que has intentado desde la interfaz de tu proveedor y cualquier mensaje de error que recibas.

Comment: Mi proveedor en este caso nic argentina no me da la opcion de verificar a travez de un registro de txt, unicamente me permite delegar el dominio

Comment: Aclaración: la verificación de la que hablo se hace en Firebase. Esto es independiente de dónde administres tu DNS. Entonces, el proceso es el mismo, donde sea que administres tus registros del DNS, ahí debes agregar el TXT que necesitas para Firebase.